# CSS inlining a Base64 image

Tags: html, css

This is my code :

```
<td height="738" valign="top" width="717" align="center" background="mail_files/paper.png">
```

I have converted the background "paper.png" to Base64 and I want to embed it there. Is there any way to do it?

I tried :

```
<td height="738" valign="top" width="717" align="center" background=url("data:image/jpeg;base64,.....Base64img.....">
```

But this did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work if you'll use proper CSS:

```
<td class="PaperCell" height="738" ...>
```

And in the CSS:

```
.PaperCell { background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,.....Base64img.....); }
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped. This method totally got out of my mind.